# Directory index forbidden by Options directive

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using the dompdf plugin for codeigniter: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PDF_generation_using_dompdf/

to generate pdfs from a form. This works on localhost, but on the live server I get this in the error log:

```
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/mm/userdata/account1/invoices/
```

Any idea what this means? I've searched for answers, and found a few that suggest editing the httpd.conf, however I don't have access to this.

I've also tried adding a blank index.html file to the root and document directory (as also suggested elsewhere, but to no avail).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, that path is correct for where I want the PDF.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for your replies. Yeah I was getting that error when I tried to view the url where the PDF should be (but it wasn't there, and neither was an index.* file). Turns out it was the file permissions of the parent blocking the PDF being generated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Either the main `httpd.conf` or the `.htaccess` file in this directory or a nearby parent directory probably includes:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Your host may have to set it to `+Indexes` if you don't have access in `.htaccess` and want to list & browse the directory contents, absent a default `index.html, index.php`, etc. If the directory should not have a default file and you don't enable `Indexes`, you may only directly target the filenames of contents within it.

The `Indexes` option is commonly disabled by default on many Apache installations.

Full details are available in [the Apache core documentation on `Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options)

Comment: what is the difference, between the `-` and the `+` ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales [Apache core docs for `Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options): _" Any options preceded by a + are added to the options currently in force, and any options preceded by a - are removed from the options currently in force"_

Comment: `Options Indexes` for me

Comment: `Options +Indexes` crashes apache for me. `Options Indexes` just doesn't work.

Comment: @Kokodoko if it "crashes" check the error log. You might be using it in an invalid context.

Answer (score 33):

It means there's no default document in that directory (index.html, index.php, etc...). On most webservers, that would mean it would show a listing of the directory's contents. But showing that directory is forbidden by server configuration (`Options -Indexes`)

Comment: If these errors are showing up a lot in my error_log, then could it be safe to assume that spiders are trying to crawl forbidden directories or should I assume users are attempting to get there?

Answer (score 20):

## The Problem

Indexes visible in a web browser for directories that do not contain an index.html or index.php file.

I had a lot of trouble with the configuration on Scientific Linux's httpd web server to stop showing these indexes.

### The Configuration that did not work

httpd.conf virtual host directory directives:

```
<Directory /home/mydomain.com/htdocs>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and the addition of the following line to .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Directory indexes were still showing up. .htaccess settings weren't working!

How could that be, other settings in .htaccess were working, so why not this one?  What's going?  It should be working! *%#$&^$%@# !!*

### The Fix

Change httpd.conf's Options line to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

and restart the webserver.

> From Apache's core mod page: ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options )
>
> Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax
>   and will be rejected during server startup by the syntax check with an
>   abort.

Voilà directory indexes were no longer showing up for directories that did not contain an index.html or index.php file.

### Now What! A New Wrinkle

New entries started to show up in the 'error_log' when such a directory access was attempted:

```
[Fri Aug 19 02:57:39.922872 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 12479] [client aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:xxxxx] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/mydomain.com/htdocs/dir-without-index-file/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

This entry is from the Apache module 'autoindex' with a LogLevel of 'error' as indicated by [autoindex:error] of the error message---the format is [module_name:loglevel].

To stop these new entries from being logged, the LogLevel needs to be changed to a higher level (e.g. 'crit') to log fewer---only more serious error messages.

#### Apache 2.4 LogLevels

See Apache 2.4's core directives for [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel).

emerg, alert, crit, error, warn, notice, info, debug, trace1, trace2, trace3, tracr4, trace5, trace6, trace7, trace8

Each level deeper into the list logs all the messages of any previous level(s).

Apache 2.4's default level is 'warn'.  Therefore, all messages classified as emerg, alert, crit, error, and warn are written to error_log.

### Additional Fix to Stop New error_log Entries

Added the following line inside the <Directory>..</Directory> section of httpd.conf:

```
LogLevel crit
```

## The Solution 1

My virtual host's httpd.conf <Directory>..</Directory> configuration:

```
<Directory /home/mydomain.com/htdocs>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    LogLevel crit
</Directory>
```

and adding to /home/*mydomain.com*/htdocs/.htaccess, the root directory of your website's .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

If you don't mind the 'error' level messages, omit

```
LogLevel crit
```

## Scientific Linux - Solution 2 - Disables mod_autoindex

No more autoindex'ing of directories inside your web space. No changes to .htaccess.  But, need access to the httpd configuration files in /etc/httpd

1. Edit /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf and comment the line:

   ```
   LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
   ```

   by adding a # in front of it then save the file.
2. In the directory /etc/httpd/conf.d rename (mv)

   ```
   sudo mv autoindex.conf autoindex.conf.<something_else>
   ```
3. Restart httpd:

   ```
   sudo httpd -k restart
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo apachectl restart
   ```

The autoindex_mod is now disabled.

## Linux distros with ap2dismod/ap2enmod Commands

Disable autoindex module enter the command

```
    sudo a2dismod autoindex
```

to enable autoindex module enter

```
    sudo a2enmod autoindex
```

Answer (score 10):

Another issue that you might run into if you're running RHEL (I ran into it) is that there is a default welcome page configured with the httpd package that will override your settings, even if you put Options Indexes. The file is in /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf. See the following link for more info:
http://wpapi.com/solved-issue-directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive/

Comment: Same thing also occurs on CentOS 6.4 and I think I saw it on 6.3 before.  

Thank you majikman, that's the third time I've run into this issue and I knew it was an easy fix but couldn't remember it offhand.

Answer (score 6):

Insert this lines:

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
        Options  +Indexes
</Directory>
```

In your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file.  I assume you are using Virtual Host for development.

And then, of course, just restart Apache.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings)

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on the same error, the problem was coming from a **syntax error in a MySql statement in my code**, in particular my $_session variable was missing a *"'*. It took hours to figure it out because on the error log the statement was misleading. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in conf.d fixed this issue for me.

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's a typo caused this issue:

```
<VirtualHost *.8080>
```

should be

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've been doing performance tuning, you might have removed mod_dir. Try putting it back and that might fix your issue.