# Directory index forbidden by Options directive error in Cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp-2.0, virtual-directory

Getting `Directory index forbidden by Options directive` error when trying to upload images but not getting that every time, so not know the exact senario, i have check the `error_logs` of apache. The .htaccess in webroot is

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>`
```

I fixed this using `+Indexes` in < Directory > but i don't know why i'm getting the error for some images only, they are of ~700 KB and ~1500 X 1700 in size.

Comment: How are you doing the upload? Can you show that code? I highly recommend the uploads plugin for this.

Comment: Maybe is happening like here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive-php-codeigniter?rq=1