# Directory index forbidden by Options directive in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, centos, thin

I Configured `SSL` for rails app running with **thin server** in **CentOS linux** environment with **apache**. When I try to open my site using `"https"` I am getting Apache error page and I checked apache error logs and got the following error message

```
 Directory index forbidden by Options directive.
```

I made some changes in **/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf** as

`"Options -Indexes"` TO  `"Options +Indexes"`

then I am getting directory structure in browser.

Please help me to solve the issue

**Update:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName XXXX
  ServerAlias www.XXXX.com

  DocumentRoot XXXX

  RewriteEngine On

  <Proxy balancer://thinservers>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3000

  </Proxy>
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://thinservers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

  ProxyPass / balancer://thinservers/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://thinservers/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  # Custom log file locations
  ErrorLog  XXXX
  CustomLog XXXX
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @User089247 I am unable to render my app when I use `https` instead it is giving me the apache error page which I have mentioned in my question. Could you Please help me. I am struggling with this from past 3 days.

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive-php-codeigniter)? Are you still getting that error message even after you did this change?

Comment: @User089247 Yes I made those changes, I am not getting error now but I am getting application directory structure in browser rather than redirecting to my application

Comment: can you post content from your apache configuration? Where you've defined `<VirtualHost *:80> ....</VirtualHost>`? It seems you have [DirectoryListings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) enabled. It says: *If no file from the DirectoryIndex directive can be located in the directory, then `mod_autoindex` can **generate a listing of the directory contents**.* Perhaps that's the reason why you're getting application's dir structure instead of pointing to application. Are you sure it's something like this: `<Directory /var/www/html/my_app/public> `?

Comment: @User089247 I updated my answer please check once

Comment: It's hard to decode the something if you've quoted everything with `XXXX` instead of relevant text, as in for `DocumentRoot XXXX` instead of `DocumentRoot /home/path/to/railsapp/public`. Also, was there a reason behind defining `Options +Indexes` in welcome.conf? Did you follow any blog/article for this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Your included Apache configuration shows the HTTP virtual host as it's litening on port 80

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

HTTPS connects to a different virtual host defined on port 443 you will need to modify this virtualhost's configuration in order to change the way the HTTPS portion of your website behaves.