# Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/Phoenix/cgi-bin/ Error in file upload

Tags: linux, apache, perl

I am trying to upload the file in UI using uploadify plugin. But file upload is not happening. I have given all file permission to all file.
 In  apache error log is showing following error :

```
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/Phoenix/cgi-bin/, referer: http://m5labncibmsrv006.gcsc.att.com/Phoenix/uploadify/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1433338019400
```

Comment: Does this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive

Comment: I have tried above solution provided in stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/ , I have added  Options  +Indexes in .htaccess file. But dint work for me