# Error 324 - No data response with Apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache

I recently started to experience this error on a web application that I deployed. It starts at random and the application will give this error for a long period of time (about 1 day or 2). If I try to access it through the direct IP instead of the DNS, it will work normally. But it's important to point out that it's not the DNS problem because I already managed to get this error when using direct address IP as well.

### Server Settings:

- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
- PHP 5.3.3
- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
- **ERROR LOG:** [Thu Jul 02 13:25:26 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/

*Note: Nothing else relevant shows up in the ERROR LOG file.*

Today, this same error happened to a different application at my localhost. The same thing as always. When accessing http://localhost/path/to/application it gives me the error and when accessing http://127.0.0.1/path/to/application it works just fine.

### My Machine:

- Windows 8.1
- WampServer 2.2
- PHP 5.6.2
- Apache 2.4.10
- **Error Log:** [Thu Jul 02 13:21:44.506151 2015] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 2428:tid 1496] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.

I'm looking for any suggestion on what I should be focusing my attention to try and figure out what is causing this problem. Any help at all.

### Side Note

My researched indicated that Google Chrome has some issue with displaying this error. This is **not** the case. When facing this problem, it will happen at any browser in the affected computer.

It is also important to mention that when one person is facing this problem, it does not mean everyone accessing the server will be facing it as well. Apparently, only people that access the application multiple times in a given day will face this error.

At the SERVER application, I've already documented 4 different people facing this problem at different computers, networks, browsers, etc;

At the localhost application (My Machine), it started today.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive

Comment: According to the link you shared, I can safely assume that the Index Options has nothing to do with the error that I'm facing, then. I do not wish to allow the server to list the files.