# Server Error 500 Centos

Tags: php, apache

Hi i have a `Centos 6 64 bit`

it has `LAMP` installed html works php doesnt work

when i try opening a php gamepanel on : `http://51.255.199.40/gpanel/` , i get `Server Error 500`,  and in the error_log of apache i get:

```
[Sat Mar 05 14:45:58 2016] [error] [client 46.99.49.96] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
```

Here is my httpd.conf my php.conf and a file named welcome.conf , php and welcome.conf are in conf.d folder and httpd.conf is in the conf folder:

http://pastebin.com/xSzPrMmi

Im not that good on coding i need help getting this fixed im since 5 days with this problem and still no fix

my email address is : benjaminselmani5@gmail.com if you guys need to contact me i will watch the topic too.

With Respect 
Benjamin Selmani

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301776/directory-index-forbidden-by-options-directive

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions on your directory for Apache to execute on it? Go to the directory and type `ll` and hit return and post the line for the directory. When in doubt, start with the permissions and work backwards.

Comment: These permision are for the html folder:

drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Mar  5 02:53 gpanel

Answer (score 1):

Change `AllowOverride None` to  `AllowOverride All` inside `httpd.conf`'s block

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```